# Nested loop not working properly

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have this code. This code evaluates the first `String` if it contains a character similar to the second `String`, and if the second `String` contains THAT character, replace that character in the second `String`  with "Q". 
The example strings are:

```
str1 = abc;
str2 = dagb;
```

In the first `String`, which is "abc", it evaluates if "a" contains in the second `String`, which is "dagb", and if so, "a" in the `String` "dagb" will be replaced with "Q" so the output will be "dQgb".

My problem is the nested loop. After finding the first character in the first `String`, it stops the output of my code "dQgb". It should continue to loop. Finding the next character, which is "b", in the first `String` "abc".

So the final output should be "dQgQ".

```
String g = "abc";
String h = "dagb";
for(int j = 0; j < g.length(); j++) {

    char c = g.charAt(j);
    for (int k = 0; k < h.length();k++) {

        char l = h.charAt(k);
        if(c == l) {
            String inputs = g.replace(c, ' ');
            String inputss = h.replace(Character.toString(l),"Q");

            input = input.replace(g, inputs);
            input = input.replace (h, inputss);
            input = input.replace (" ", "");
            // break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What is input in your case, how are you using it and would give us the whole context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix your code, but you can use this:

```
String g = "abc";
String h = "dagb";
for(int j = 0; j < g.length();j++){
    char c = g.charAt(j);
    h = h.replace(c,'Q');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a `StringBuilder` because it's *mutable*, then call `String.contains(CharSequence)` to determine if the value is present in the first `String`. Something like,

```
String g = "abc";
String h = "dagb";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(h);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    if (g.contains(String.valueOf(sb.charAt(i)))) {
        sb.setCharAt(i, 'Q');
    }
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Which outputs (as requested)

```
dQgQ
```

Comment: what if Q is a string ? or a string like "hello"?

Comment: @JohnOtom I might suggest a regular expression in that case, but that is inherently more complex than what you have asked (which is already unusual in practice).